# Binding list object to javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, binding

My Model lokes something like this

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public List<Item> Items {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I know that I can bind `Name` to JavaScript in my view(.cshtml) like this: `var jsName = '@Model.Name'`

The question is how do I bind List to an array?
I want to do something like this

`var Array = @Model.Itmes` and then be able to iterate this array via JavaScript.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mate's answer would work.  Another option to turn your model into a JSON object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var items = model.Items;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. By the way I don't think that you should have semicolon after @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))